# getting css style property using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a image `draggable` and would like to save it via PHP so I decided to get the inner style and  put it as value in input field, so I can get it via `$_POST`, but I am unable to find like if it would be a inner `HTML` data I could have get it via calling `innerHTML` syntax, but like so is there any way of getting style for the image

```
<div class="scott_img">
            <img id="uploadPreview" src="<?php echo (empty($data['profile_pic'])) ? "images/profile.jpg" : "uploads/" . $data['profile_pic']; ?>" style="style goes here">
            <span class="scouttag"></span>

        </div>
        <form method="POST" action="profile.php?uid=<?php echo $uid; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="text-align:center;">
            <input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="image" style="margin:auto;" />
            <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
            <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
            <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
            <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
            <input type="hidden" id="uploadPreview1" value="need style here so i can save it to database" />
            <button type="submit" name="update_picture" class="btn_form">Update Picture</button>
        </form> 

        <img class="scott_line"src="images/line.png">

         <script>
            (function() {
                var elem = document.getElementById('uploadPreview');
                var val  = getComputedStyle(elem);
                document.getElementById('uploadPreview1').value = val;
              var $section = $('.scott_img').first();
              $section.find('#uploadPreview').panzoom({
                $zoomRange: $section.find(".zoom-range"),
                $reset: $section.find(".reset")
              });
            })();
          </script>
```

Thank you

Comment: what did `getComputedStyle(elem)` returns?

Comment: value="[object CSSStyleDeclaration]"

Answer (score 2):

> if you get element **style** tag (inline css)

```
   var a = document.getElementById('uploadPreview');
    var b=  a.getAttribute('style');
    alert(b);
```

**if you get element css**

```
var element = document.getElementById('uploadPreview'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    top = style.getPropertyValue('top');
```

Comment: by using first i am getting null and your second point will only get value top i need these styles

Comment: transform: matrix(2, 0, 0, 1, -90, 7); backface-visibility: hidden; transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px; cursor: move; transition: none;

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how and why you are going to use this server-side, but if you believe that's the right thing to do, just stringify the JSON object:

```
var val = JSON.stringify(getComputedStyle(elem));
```

Comment: style properties and style is this style="transform: matrix(2, 0, 0, 1, -2, 25); backface-visibility: hidden; transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px; cursor: move; transition: none;" and i got everything as animation etc etc

Comment: then is there anyother way i can get is i am getting it because when the image uis uploaded i need to save the style as when i will show image on user end the style will also be retrieved this is i am doing because i have placed image draggable jquery

Comment: So, it's much more complicated than simple images. It looks to me something like [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com) can help you to take a screenshot from that portion of screen.

Answer (score 0):

since the Css value is in an input you have to get it via:

```
Var x = Document.getElementById("").value
```

Then in your java script, append the Css rules by doing;

```
X.style.width = Y;
Or div.style.color = "#ccc";
```

**Hope you get the point**

Comment: var elem = document.getElementById('uploadPreview').value; i got undefined in return

Comment: UploadPreview is the id for the image.  You need to get the ids of the input boxes with the Css style values. According to ur code above, thats the hidden fields

Comment: This is the style i want to get transform: matrix(2, 0, 0, 1, -90, 7); backface-visibility: hidden; transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px; cursor: move; transition: none;

Comment: Yes, you can write all that using just javascript as instructed above

Answer (score 0):

You can get an element's CSS style in JS and transform it into JSON like so:

`var elementCSS = JSON.stringify(document.getElementById('uploadPreview').style)`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use simple jQuery to get style value like below?

```
var imgstyle = $("#uploadPreview").attr("style"); //this will get your whole value of style attribute.
$("#uploadPreview1").val(imgstyle); //this will update hidden field's value.
```

also it seems that it is going to be different on each upload. So you can put this above code inside your draggable or file uplaod's change event.